# What are the error values for find_get_pid() kernel function?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, pid

I am using `find_get_pid()` call to obtain the `struct pid *` for a given `pid_t pid` i.e process id. However I want to include some sanity checks as the `pid` value will be supplied by a user process, let's say user gives a pid value of `123` and no process with `pid` 123 exists, in that case what will be the error value returned by `find_get_pid`. Will it return a `NULL` pointer ?

The sample code stub is as follows:

```
    struct pid *pid_struct;
    struct task_struct *task;

    pid_struct = find_get_pid(pid);
 /* INSERT SANITY CHECK ON pid_struct ? */
    task = pid_task(pid_struct, PIDTYPE_PID);
```

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? Maybe the kernel mailing list could help with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`find_get_pid` returns a NULL pointer if the pid could not be found.

Found this empirically by trying some invalid pids.